# Rails link_to not working within a button element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, routes, link-to

I have the following HTML and .erb code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><%= link_to "Customer Information", customer_information_path %></button>
```

The link renders fine, but does nothing when clicked.

Here is my routes file:

```
  devise_scope :user do
   root :to => "devise/sessions#new"
  end

  get "hub" => "pages#hub"
  get "customer_information" => "pages#customer_information"
```

And here is my pages controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

 def hub
 end

 def customer_information
 end

end
```

The code does not throw any error.

Thoughts?

Comment: is there a view at `app/views/pages/customer_information.html.erb` ?

Comment: Could you add a little more information as to why you need a button?

Comment: Yes, the customer_information.html.erb file does exist in my views.

Comment: The button is part of a navigation bar.

Comment: So, is it possible to lose the button and style the link as a button?

Comment: @vee Have not tried, no reason it's not possible.  Are you saying the issue is a conflict with the button element?

Comment: I don't have a reference to show you at the moment, but anchor tag will mark the text within the anchor tags as hyperlink, so clicking the button part outside of the anchor tag is not going to work because there is no link on the button.  More information on [`anchor tag`](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/1995-archive/Elements/A.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following revisions work:

```
<ul>
  <li><%= link_to "Customer Information", customer_information_path, :class => "btn btn-default btn-lg" %></li>
</ul>
```

So it would seem applying the class to the link_to element generates the CSS results and still allows the link to function.

Answer (score 7):

The `link_to` helper produces an `<a>` element and you can't put an `<a>` inside a `<button>`, that would violate [the content model for `<button>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/forms.html#the-button-element):

> **Content model:**
>   Phrasing content, but there must be no interactive content descendant.

and [*interactive content*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#interactive-content-0) includes `<a>`. If you feed a browser a `<button><a></a></button>`, then it might rewrite the HTML to be valid or it might not let the click get to the `<a>`.

Consider using [`button_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) to produce the `<button>` instead of `<button>` and `link_to` or try adding a click handler to the `<button>` in JavaScript. Using `button_to` might complicate your CSS though as `button_to` will add a lot of extra markup (such as `<form>`s and `<div>`s). Another option might be to use only `<a>` elements in the toolbar but style them to look like buttons, then you could just use `link_to` for the whole toolbar.

Comment: The OP could actually just use `link_to` instead of `button` or `button_to` as the link is in the navigation and not within a `form`.  I saw this more to be a styling a link question that is at the same time digging for solid information as you've pointed in the first part of your answer.

Comment: @vee you're right - instead of generating the button element I just applied the button class to the link_to method and it worked.  Thanks for the info, I appreciate the help.

Comment: @vee: I thought "Another option might be to use only `<a>` elements in the toolbar but style them to look like buttons, then you could just use `link_to` for the whole toolbar." covered that, perhaps I could have been more explicit though.

Comment: @vee: No worries, I'm not trying to pick a fight or hostile, just wondering if I missed something or something wasn't clear. Anyway, I think Dustin's answer fills in any gaps in mine so we're all good.

Answer (score 2):

**Button**

Building on `mu is too short`'s answer, you have to consider what a `button` is there to do -

> The  tag defines a clickable button.
>
> Inside a  element you can put content, like text or images.
>   This is the difference between this element and buttons created with
>   the  element.

As alluded to by `mu is too short`, the `button` element is standalone (cannot include any other element inside). This means if you want to use the button to create a link, you'll have to think differently about what you're trying to achieve

--

**button_to**

Rails has two ways of achieving a "link":

- [`button_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to)
- [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

What you'll be looking for is likely `button_to`:

```
<%= button_to "New", new_articles_path %>
# => "<form method="post" action="/articles/new" class="button_to">
#      <div><input value="New" type="submit" /></div>
#    </form>"
```

This, as you can see by the demo above, creates a simple form which allows you to send data to an endpoint. This might seem overkill for a link, but it's the best way to create a "native" HTML button. Alternatively, you could *style* your `link` as a button too

```
<%= button_to "Customer Information", customer_information_path, method: :get, class: "btn btn-default btn-lg"
```

Comment: Thanks for this info - as a follow up question, if I am linking to a static page, should I just use pure HTML or is it considered best practice to continue using Rails?